# Another error when installing RMySQL in Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, windows, r

I have a Windows 8.1 machine and use R 3.0.3 and RTools 30. I'm trying to install RMySQL and I followed the instructions from http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/ and another StackOverflow posts but I get this error over and over:

> ```
>   installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
>   package 'RMySQL' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>  0 [main] sh 3240 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
>  the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
>  checking for $MYSQL_HOME... â€C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/â€
>  test: Files/MySQL/MySQL: unknown operand
>  cygwin warning:
>    MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/x64/Rscript
>    Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/x64/Rscript
>    CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
>    Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
>      http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
>   libs
>  Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
>  so building only the main architecture
>
>        0 [main] make 4640 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
>  the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
>  cygwin warning:
>    MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf
>    Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf
>    CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
>    Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
>      http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
>  gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I"â€C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/â€"/include    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o
>  RS-DBI.c: In function 'RS_na_set':
>  RS-DBI.c:1219:11: warning: variable 'c' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>  gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I"â€C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/â€"/include    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c RS-MySQL.c -o RS-MySQL.o
>  In file included from RS-MySQL.c:22:0:
>  RS-MySQL.h:32:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
>  compilation terminated.
>  make: *** [RS-MySQL.o] Error 1
>  Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="RMySQL.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RS-DBI.o RS-MySQL.o"' had status 2
>  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'
>   removing 'C:/Users/Yohanan/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/RMySQL'
>  Warning in install.packages :
>    running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Yohanan\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" C:\Users\Yohanan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpysBrc8/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1
>  Warning in install.packages :
>    installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
> ```

Can you please help me? Thank you...

Comment: It looks like you MYSQL_HOME variable has junk in it (possibly quotes that you thought were surrounding it but in fact are part of it).

Comment: Wrote it again and get a different error... now it says: "Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RMySQL', details:
  call: utils::readRegistry("SOFTWARE\\MySQL AB", hive = "HLM", maxdepth = 2)
  error: Registry key 'SOFTWARE\MySQL AB' not found"

Comment: There is something wrong with your MySQL installation. Re-install it.

Comment: I did and get the same error!

Comment: There is likely a problem with your MySQL installation. It seems its not setting the registry correctly.

Comment: Problem solved!!! It was just a tiny \ at the end of the MySQL_HOME path in the Renviron.site file... oh my!

Answer (score 0):

**Probably something went wrong with your MySQL installation.**

**The error refers to registry keys missing as documented here:**  [MySQL Manual - MySQL Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-wizard.html),  searching for *SOFTWARE\MySQL AB* reveals the section stating how the registry should look like. With **regedit**.exe you can fix this yourself.

Information on how to use regedit.exe: [Techsupportalert - Regedit in One Easy Lesson](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/learn-how-use-windows-registry-editor-regedit-one-easy-lesson.htm)

*It worked for me with the same problem*